# how to deploy angular 10 app on Microsoft IIS with i18n support

Tags: angular, iis, internationalization

I am developing an Angular 10 app with i18n support, and I want to deploy this app on Microsoft IIS in french on https://example.com/admin/fr and in english on https://example.com/admin/en-US

In file "index.html", I have set :   
In file "angular.json", I have added :

```
  "i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "en-US",
    "locales": {
      "fr": {
        "translation": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf"
      }
    }
  },
```

In environment files, I have added : baseHref: '/admin'

When I compile with option : "localize": ["fr"] in file "angular.json", I get a working french app on my dev server at https://localhost:4200/admin

When I compile with option : "localize": ["en-US"] in file "angular.json", I get a working english app on my dev server at https://localhost:4200/admin

I have read the Angular doc at https://angular.io/guide/i18n#deploy-locales and https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration to understand how to deploy in production on IIS.

I have set the rewrite rules as mentioned, set "localize": true in file "angular.json" to get all the localized apps in one build, and, as I am developing in MyEclipse on Windows, I run the build with the command:
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --base-href "/admin/"

The "fr" and the "en-US" folders get well generated in the "dist" folder, and I copy them under the "admin" folder of my IIS web site.

When I go to  https://example.com/admin/fr, I get this error in browser console: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'fr'

When I go to  https://example.com/admin/en-US, I get the same error in browser console: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'en-US'

I did not find any valuable information to solve this in Angular doc or by googling few hours, so any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: you could try to set the iis URL rewrite rule: `<rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/admin/" />
            </rule>`

Comment: I already use this rewrite rule when I deploy Angular app not localized, and it works fine. Unfortunately, it does not work for localized app.

Comment: you could refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49898662

Comment: I had found this solution but it is OK only when your app is deployed under the root folder of your web site, not if you deploy under a subfolder, which is what I needed. I spent some time to find how to configure base href in Angular and rewrite rules in IIS, that's why I posted how to do it to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I did it, so if anyone else has same problem, here is my solution.

In Angular file "index.html":

```
<base href="/myapp">
```

No "baseHref" parameter in Angular environment files.

In Angular file « angular.json » :

```
      "i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "en",
    "locales": {        
      "fr": {
        "translation": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf"
      }
    }
  },
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "localize": true,
```

To build Angular apps for all locales at once using MyEclipse on Windows 10:

```
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --baseHref="/myapp"
```

Folders "dist/en" and "dist/fr" get updated with new builds.

In IIS :

- Create a virtual directory "myapp" pointing to a local folder. This is not mandatory, you can also simply use a "myapp" folder located under the root folder of your target web site.
- Add a "web.config" file in the root folder of your target web site with the following rules

  ```
               <rule name="Angular Routes EN" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="myapp\/en.*" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="myapp/en" />
           </rule>
           <rule name="Angular Routes FR" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="myapp\/fr.*" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="myapp/fr" />
           </rule>
  ```

Your Angular app is then accessible using :

https://myexample.com/myapp/en for the EN version
https://myexample.com/myapp/fr for the FR version

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: This helped for me with getting the localized folders to work but then deep linking no longer works. I can only get deep linking to work when I removed the language builds and just have the regular Angular app running under the subfolder similar to your myapp folder. Did you solve deep linking on your site?

Answer (score 3):

I've tried the first solution and it didn't work.
I've found another solution:
My app will be the only one on IIS server.

In Angular file "index.html":

```
<base href="/">
```

To build Angular apps for all locales at once:

```
ng build --prod
```

Folders "dist/en" and "dist/fr" get updated with new builds.

In IIS:
Copy "en" and "fr" folders from dist to wwwroot (IIS root folder).
Create a file in "wwwroot/en" named web.config.
Put the following code in it:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/en/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Do the same thing for "/fr" folder. Be careful to change "/en/" to "/fr/:

You can add an index.html in the wwwroot folder. Depending of the language that the user has set up in his browser, the browser will be redirected to one of the two folders. English is the default one.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    let userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
    console.log('userLang:' + userLang);
    if (userLang != null && typeof userLang !== undefined && userLang.includes('fr')) {
        userLang = 'fr';
    } else {
        userLang = 'en';
    }
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '/' + userLang;
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Just to be sure everything is fine, go to wwwroot/en/index.html and check the base href is defined like this.

```
<base href="/en/">
```

Do the same for french version, wwwroot/fr/index.html. It should be

```
<base href="/fr/">
```

My angular.json is like this:

```
        "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en",
        "locales": {
          "en": {
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
            "baseHref": "/en/"
          },
          "fr": {
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
            "baseHref": "/fr/"
          }
        }
      },
        ...
        "en": {
          "localize": ["en"]
        },
        "fr": {
          "localize": ["fr"]
        }
        ...
        "en": {
          "browserTarget": "web-order-portal:build:en"
        },
        "fr": {
          "browserTarget": "web-order-portal:build:fr"
        }
        ...
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "web-order-portal:build"
          }
        },
```

Update:
You can automatically copy the needed files (index.html and web.config) on the /dist/en and /dist/fr folders by using post hooks:
Go on the package.json file and add the following code:

```
"build": "ng build --prod",
"postbuild": "copy src\\locale\\dist\\index.html dist\\ /Y && copy src\\locale\\dist\\en\\web.config dist\\en /Y && copy src\\locale\\dist\\fr\\web.config dist\\fr /Y",
```