# IIS with localized Angular application

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting

I'm using angular (version 10) i18n localization in ASP.NET application. After deploy I can open my app and use navigation, but after page refresh I got

> {"StatusCode":500,"Message":"Internal Server Error occured."}

I tried to use rewrite rules like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745238/how-to-deploy-angular-10-app-on-microsoft-iis-with-i18n-support) question, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for the 500 error, you need to further analyze this error, I suggest you try to use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

More information about the use of failed request tracking you can refer to this link: [Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in IIS rewrite rules.
If you have same problem, try to do this:

1. Open your `app.module.ts`
2. In import block add or replace RouterModule with this

> RouterModule.forRoot(***your_routes***, {useHash: true})